# How do I get the substr after a word or index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I have the following element below in my DOM.

```
<div id="klarna-checkout-container" style="overflow-x: hidden;">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(w,k,i,d,n,c,l){
    w[k]=w[k]||function(){(w[k].q=w[k].q||[]).push(arguments)};
    l=w[k].config={
      container:w.document.getElementById(i),
      ORDER_URL:'https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com/yaco/orders/1234-fa14-4a0f-bf2d-5678',
      AUTH_HEADER:'KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6',
      LOCALE:'sv-SE',
      ORDER_STATUS:'checkout_incomplete',
      MERCHANT_TAC_URI:'https://demo.krokedil.se/klarnacheckout/terms/',
      MERCHANT_NAME:'K500956',
      GUI_OPTIONS:[],
      ALLOW_SEPARATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:true,
      PURCHASE_COUNTRY:'swe',
      PURCHASE_CURRENCY:'SEK',
      TESTDRIVE:true,
      CHECKOUT_DOMAIN:'https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com',
      BOOTSTRAP_SRC:'https://a.klarnacdn.net/kcoc/6788-345/checkout.bootstrap.js',
      CLIENT_EVENT_HOST:'https://evt.playground.klarna.com'
    };
    n=d.createElement('script');
    c=d.getElementById(i);
    n.async=!0;
    n.src=l.BOOTSTRAP_SRC;
    c.appendChild(n);
    try{
      ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =
        l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST + '/v1/checkout/snippet/load' +
        '?sid=' + l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1) +
        '&order_status=' + w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS) +
        '&timestamp=' + (new Date).getTime();
    }catch(e){}
    })(this,'_klarnaCheckout','klarna-checkout-container',document);
    /* ]]&gt; */
    </script>

</div>
```

I want to get the value after the word called `AUTH_HEADER:`. So the value I am looking for is `KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6`

I tried using the code below but it needs improvement.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var get_klarna_checkout_container = $('#klarna-checkout-container').text().trim();
  var klarna_checkout_container_index = get_klarna_checkout_container.indexOf('AUTH_HEADER:');
  var klarna_checkout_container_index_2 = get_klarna_checkout_container.substr(klarna_checkout_container_index, 289);

  console.log(klarna_checkout_container_index_2);


 });
</script>
```

The output of console.log above is:

> AUTH_HEADER:'KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6',
>           LOCALE:'sv-SE',
>           ORDER_STATUS:'checkout_incomplete',
>           MERCHANT_TAC_URI:'https://demo.krokedil.se/klarnacheckout/terms/',
>           MERCHANT_NAME:'K500956',
>           GUI_OPTIONS:[],
>           ALLOW_SEPARATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:true,
>           PURCHASE_CO

I am aiming for `KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6`

The problem with my code above is that it prints a lot of string instead of just adding characters from what I added in substr method.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please make your post more readable - the code is quite messy and not very easy to read. And what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @JackBashford  Sorry for the messy code. I have updated my question above. You'll see the output of console.log outputs a lot of string instead of adding only a few characters starting from the index and end index.

Comment: What is the type of output? What does `console.log(typeof klarna_checkout_container_index_2)` show?

Comment: @JackBashford I have updated my answer above. console.log now has an output

Comment: But what is the type of `klarna_checkout_container_index_2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went the regex route.  The line to look for is

```
var found = klarna_checkout_container_index_2.match(/AUTH_HEADER:'(.+)'/);
```

```js
    var get_klarna_checkout_container = $('#klarna-checkout-container').text().trim();
  var klarna_checkout_container_index = get_klarna_checkout_container.indexOf('AUTH_HEADER:');

  
  var klarna_checkout_container_index_2 = get_klarna_checkout_container.substr(klarna_checkout_container_index, 289);


var found = klarna_checkout_container_index_2.match(/AUTH_HEADER:'(.+)'/);

console.log(found[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="klarna-checkout-container" style="overflow-x: hidden;">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(w,k,i,d,n,c,l){
    w[k]=w[k]||function(){(w[k].q=w[k].q||[]).push(arguments)};
    l=w[k].config={
      container:w.document.getElementById(i),
      ORDER_URL:'https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com/yaco/orders/1234-fa14-4a0f-bf2d-5678',
      AUTH_HEADER:'KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6',
      LOCALE:'sv-SE',
      ORDER_STATUS:'checkout_incomplete',
      MERCHANT_TAC_URI:'https://demo.krokedil.se/klarnacheckout/terms/',
      MERCHANT_NAME:'K500956',
      GUI_OPTIONS:[],
      ALLOW_SEPARATE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:true,
      PURCHASE_COUNTRY:'swe',
      PURCHASE_CURRENCY:'SEK',
      TESTDRIVE:true,
      CHECKOUT_DOMAIN:'https://checkout-eu.playground.klarna.com',
      BOOTSTRAP_SRC:'https://a.klarnacdn.net/kcoc/6788-345/checkout.bootstrap.js',
      CLIENT_EVENT_HOST:'https://evt.playground.klarna.com'
    };
    n=d.createElement('script');
    c=d.getElementById(i);
    n.async=!0;
    n.src=l.BOOTSTRAP_SRC;
    c.appendChild(n);
    try{
      ((w.Image && (new w.Image))||(d.createElement && d.createElement('img'))||{}).src =
        l.CLIENT_EVENT_HOST + '/v1/checkout/snippet/load' +
        '?sid=' + l.ORDER_URL.split('/').slice(-1) +
        '&order_status=' + w.encodeURIComponent(l.ORDER_STATUS) +
        '&timestamp=' + (new Date).getTime();
    }catch(e){}
    })(this,'_klarnaCheckout','klarna-checkout-container',document);
    /* ]]&gt; */
    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: You have the correct output. I would like to ask what does the line `match(/AUTH_HEADER:'(.+)'/)` means?

Comment: That's a regular expression, which is string pattern matching.  How you can read it is look for a pattern that literally has AUTH_HEADER:' followed by any character multiple times and capture that value to use later, followed by another single quote.

Comment: The crucial bit that captures the value is (.+).  The "." is a wildcard for any character, the "+" is the number of characters, which is one or more.   The point is regular expressions is powerful but a bit esoteric, which is why a lot of people don't like it, but I recommend it usually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It worked like a charm. The problem I faced with the substr is that I was not able to determine the number characters after getting index.

Comment: One last thing to take note of.  When doing a pattern match like I'm doing, the match returns an array, with the first index being the entire string pattern caught.  The other indexes are the explicit matches, which is why I logged found[1] rather than found or found[0]

Comment: Glad to help.  If you go to regex101.com, it presents you with a workplace and documentation on the side so you can see if your pattern is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think function substr is wrong.

```
string.substr(beginIndex, length);
```

If you want to get only 'KlarnaCheckout 76c9bumqmkt8oy7wcpnr6'
 Please use:

```
var klarna_checkout_container_index = get_klarna_checkout_container.indexOf('AUTH_HEADER:') + 12;
var klarna_checkout_container_index_2 = get_klarna_checkout_container.substr(klarna_checkout_container_index, 36);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But do you know how to adjust your answer if I am not sure how many characters it will be single quotes after the word AUTH_HEADER: ?

Answer (score 2):

```
//This is one way to do it. Hope it helps.

    let div = document.querySelector("#klarna-checkout-container script").innerText,
    str = div.split(","),
    authHeader;
for(let index in str){
    let temp = str[index].split(":");
    if(temp[0].trim() === "AUTH_HEADER"){
        authHeader = temp[1].trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you split the text with the key + ":'", second item of splitted index will contain the value at index 0 and then you can split it again with "'" or "'," which first element of its result will contain the value you are looking for.

```
const getHeaderValue = function (text, toFind) {
  return text.split(toFind + ":'")[1].split("'")[0];
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var container = $('#klarna-checkout-container').text().trim()
  console.log(getHeaderValue(container, 'AUTH_HEADER'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your code currently outputs, just do this:

```
if (typeof klarna_checkout_container_index_2 == "string") {
    klarna_checkout_container_index_2 = JSON.parse(klarna_checkout_container_index_2);
}
console.log(klarna_checkout_container_index_2["AUTH_HEADER"]);
```